# How should I generate an isometric image of a Minecraft skin in PHP?

Tags: php, 3d, isometric

I'm trying to generate 3D isometric views of players' heads, but I'm not sure what kind of support PHP has for this type of operation, or of any external libraries that may be better suited.

Basically I need to take a net like [this](http://minotar.net/skin/steve.png) ([here](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/images/0/01/Skinzones.png) is a diagram showing what each portion is mapped to) and make a 3D head from it. I also need to include the 'head accessory' portions, which should be slightly larger/offset from the actual head.

Does anyone know how I should go about this?

Comment: i don't think you will have much luck with the internal php graphic functions.

Comment: @Dragon that's what I was thinking... Do you know of any libraries with better support? I'm new to image processing in PHP.

Comment: If you are working ONLY with the heads from minecraft, you could possibly write your own code to handle it and use the internal graphic functions. The model itself is pretty simple from what I understand (haven't actually played it though) and the math functions wouldn't be too amazingly tricky. The only thing that I think is painfully missing is the ability to capture a triangular section of image and transfer it to another triangular section of image. The rest of it could pretty easily be done by working from the back of the image to the front which would ensure the right visibility.

Comment: Or use WebGL and actually render it in 3D

Comment: @Petah I only want to output a PNG..

Comment: @DC_ well theoretically you could use `wkhtmltoimage` from there to convert it to a PNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first it will be a complex job in my view.

The http://www.minecraftwiki.net/images/0/01/Skinzones.png file you mentioned is flat, but you have to convert that in ISOMETRIC 3D look, so you have to distort the images

For example look at the images below

[image: 3D Box]
[image: Box Front Side]
[image: Box Left Side]

So you can see that 3D box image is created from the pieces of other images, the logic is to add perspective to the flat images and join them. but as it is 2D we will call it Image Distortion.

Unfortunately GD Library which comes bundled with PHP is not advanced enough to let you do such things.

You have to use some other library like Image Magic and this link is tutorial for using distort functions http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/

Second big thing is the processing of the images, you can process the images live but it will consume lots of resources on server, so it is suggested that you use pre processed images, and not process them every time.

To generate the Isometric image you have to write the code your self, and it may need alteration on each image character  depending upon the size of the image. But when you have written a code it will be easy.

My Suggestion is to write your own code once, then alter it for every character and save the processed images in a sprite and use them when you add play functionality.

check out this link as well

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php